# How Does Ramanujan’s Master Theorem Work?

Tags: analysis, mellin-transform

I am trying to understand Ramanujan' Master theorem, but I really can't seem to wrap my head around it. So the theorem states that if you have a function $F$ such that you can write it as

> $$F(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac {w(k)(-x)^k}{k!}$$

for some analytic or integrable function $w$, then the Mellin transform of $F$ is

> $$I=\int_0^\infty x^{n-1}F(x)dx= \Gamma(n)w(-n).$$

However, there are some related parts that confuse me:

1. The definition of $w$ by the series in the first expression just requires $w$ to take certain values for $k=0,1,\ldots,\infty$, but not for any values in $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{N}_0$. Is this really enough to uniquely define $w$? If so why?

A typical example would be $w(k)=1$ for all $k$. In that case, we get $F(x)=e^{-x}$ and $I=\Gamma(n)$. However, if I instead use $w(k)=cos(2\pi k)$, then I still get $F(x)=e^{-x}$. However, for this $w$ I get $I(n)=\Gamma(n)cos(-2\pi n)$, which agrees on $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ but not anywhere else. Obviously, these can't both be correct. Both $w$ are integrable, so why is one of the choices of $w$ incorrect?

2. (this is likely related to the first) Why do we require the minus in the expression? If we define some function $\hat{w}$ such that $\hat{w}(k)=(-1)^k w(k)$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}_0$, then writing the series in terms of $\hat{w}$ would give the more familiar Maclauren series.

As an example take $w(k)=cos(2\pi k)$. No if I choose $\hat{w}(k)=(cos(\pi k))^2$ (note the factor $2$ is missing), then

> $$F(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac {\hat{w}(k)(x)^k}{k!}$$

is a Maclauren series for $e^{-x}$. Why can't we get a similar result for the Maclauren series?

Comment: See also: [Functional analysis proof of Ramanujan's Master Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2079172)

Answer (score 3):

> You should think to the residue theorem and Mellin inversion. The **decay and analycity** conditions implies that knowing $\varphi(-k)$ is enough to know $\varphi(s)$.

Let $ \varphi(s)$ be analytic on $\Re(s) \le 0$, such that $e^{-|t|\pi / 2 }\varphi(it)$ has exponential decay, $\varphi(0) = 0$, and such that for some $x_0 > 0$ $$\lim_{T \to \pm \infty} \int_{-\infty}^0 |\Gamma(\sigma+iT) \varphi(\sigma+iT) x_0^{-\sigma}| d\sigma = 0,\qquad \lim_{\sigma \to -\infty} x_0^{-\sigma}\int_{-\infty}^\infty |\Gamma(\sigma+it) \varphi(\sigma+it)| dt = 0$$

then

- for all $x > 0$ $$f(x)=\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{-i\infty}^{i\infty} \Gamma(s)\varphi(s)x^{-s}ds$$ $f$ is analytic and bounded on $x > 0$
- for $x \in (0,x_0]$ $$\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{-i\infty}^{i\infty} \Gamma(s)\varphi(s)x^{-s}ds = \sum Res(\Gamma(s)\varphi(s)x^{-s}) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \varphi(-k) \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}x^k$$

Thus $f(x), x >0$ is the analytic continuation of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\varphi(-k) (-1)^k}{k!}x^k , |x| < |x_0|$ and by inverse Fourier/Mellin transform, for $\Re(s) \in (-1,0)$ $$\Gamma(s)\varphi(s) = 
 \int_0^\infty f(x) x^{s-1}dx$$

Comment: I am not sure, that I fully understand your answer. Do I understand you correctly, that $\varphi$ being analytic is NOT sufficient for it to work in the master theorem? So it has to be analytic AND have exponential decay AND satisfy these limits you give in the first part of your post. Is this correct? Then I could understand, why this limits the choices and that we may be able to tell $\varphi(-s)$ when we know $\varphi(s)$.

Comment: @LiKao I just renamed your $w(-s)$ in $\varphi(s)$. The exponential decay of $\Gamma(it)\varphi(it)$ is a major point : this is what we need to ensure $f(x)=\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{-i\infty}^{i\infty} \Gamma(s)\varphi(s)x^{-s}ds$ is analytic so it is fully defined by its Taylor series at $0$. To conclude all we need is that on some interval $f(x)= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\varphi(-k) (-1)^k}{k!}x^k $ (which follows from the residue theorem which we can apply from the limit conditions)