# How was this formula made by Srinavasa Ramanujan derived?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, contour-integration, analytic-number-theory, gamma-function

I'm wondering how this formula was derived. I'm looking for a proof. My guess is that there was a substitution made, and through contour integration or something, it was shown that the limits don't change even when $\phi(n)$ isn't real.
Here's the formula

$ \begin{array}{l}
\int\limits ^{\infty }_{0} t^{s-1} \cdot f( t) dt=\Gamma ( s) \cdot \phi ( -s) ,\text{ if } f( t) =\sum\limits ^{\infty }_{n=0}\frac{\phi ( n)}{n!}( -t)^{n}\\
\end{array}$

And I think $\phi(n)$ can be any sequence.

Comment: Do you have a source for this formula?

Comment: It is Ramanujan's master theorem. You need stronger conditions (decay, analyticity), as it is it is not true. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3281841/how-does-ramanujan-s-master-theorem-work/3281987#3281987