# What are the conditions for Ramanujan's Master Theorem to hold?

Tags: integration, summation, power-series, mellin-transform

Ramanujan's Master Theorem states that if

$$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\phi(k)}{k!}(-x)^k$$

then $$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{s-1}f(x)\ dx = \Gamma(s)\phi(-s).$$

But there are obviously some conditions on $\phi$ as you could just define it to be $0$ for negative inputs or multiply it by $\cos(2\pi k)$ without changing $f$ but giving a different result. What are these conditions?

Comment: google is your friend. See [here](http://math.tulane.edu/%7Evhm/papers_html/rmt-final.pdf)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Functional analysis proof of Ramanujan's Master Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2079172/functional-analysis-proof-of-ramanujans-master-theorem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a [reference](https://arminstraub.com/downloads/pub/rmt.pdf). I am frustrated that Wikipedia and Wolfram MathWorld both state the theorem poorly. Here is the precise statement:

> **Ramanujan’s Master Theorem**: Let $\varphi(z)$ be an analytic (single-valued) function, defined on a half-plane $$H(\delta)=\left\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\Re(z)\geq -\delta\right\}$$ for some $0<\delta<1$. Suppose that, for some $A<\pi$, $\varphi$ satisfies the growth condition $$\left|\varphi\left(u+iv\right)\right|<Ce^{Pu+A|v|}$$ for all $z=u+iv\in H(\delta)$. Then, $$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{s-1}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\Gamma(s)\varphi(-s)$$ with $$f(x):=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\varphi(n)(-x)^n}{n!}$$ for all $0<\Re(s)<\delta$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! However from this definition it is still not obvious to me why there can't be different $\phi$ that are equal at every integer, generating the same function but results in different answers.

Comment: @NoaArvidsson Such a function would no longer be analytic.

Comment: I don't undersdtand why that's the case. If $\phi$ is analytic then a function like $\phi(n)+\sin(\pi n)$ would still be analytic. I assume the problem is that something like that wouldn't satisfy the growth condition, but I still don't understand why there can only be one unique $\phi$ for every function.

Comment: @NoaArvidsson I thought you meant a function that we would let be zero on the negative reals, which in that case would no longer be analytic as we would no longer have smoothness. The problem with your $\phi(n)+\sin(\pi n)$ example is indeed the growth condition as $\sin(z)$ is unbounded on $\mathbb{C}$ by Liouville’s theorem. In particular, however, it grows faster than the necessary exponential-type bound by Nachbin's and Carlson’s theorems. To apply Mellin inversion, one requires necessary growth bounds on $\Gamma(s)\varphi(-s)$. See the Wikipedia page on the Mellin inversion theorem.

Comment: @NoaArvidsson A detailed account of this version can be found in Hardy's _Ramanujan_